# Another picture puzzle - should be a lot easier to bag this one

Tags: riddle, visual

The images below are connected by a single word:

[image: A Brick Wall]

[image: A person's Back]

[image: A Cup]

[image: Sand]

[image: A Fly]

[image: A Hat]

[image: A Towel]

[image: An Aeroplane]

What is the word, and what are the connections?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is:

> Paper

Brick Wall

> Wallpaper

Back

> Paper Back

Cup

> Paper Cup

Sand

> Sand Paper

Fly

> Fly Paper

Hat

> Paper Hat

Towel

> Paper Towel

Plane

> Paper Plane / Plain Paper

Title

> Paper Bag

Comment: Clearly too easy.  +1